# Swift Too many Cocoa pods?

Tags: cocoa, sdk, cocoapods, risk-analysis

So I am creating an app that uses Firebase, Google maps SDK, Core location and loads of other little third party things going on, but is there a point where all these pods become too many? What are the negatives to having this many pods other than the obvious large project and IPA file size?

To give you an idea of how many pods I have here is my pod file list

```
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/AdMob'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
pod 'GooglePlaces'
pod 'GooglePlacesSearchController'
pod 'CVCalendar', '~> 1.6.0'
pod 'SDWebImage', '~> 4.0'
pod 'GeoFire', :git => 'https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc.git'
pod 'VMLocationManager', :git => 'https://github.com/varshylmobile/LocationManager.git'
pod 'BraintreeDropIn'
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
pod 'HFSwipeView'
pod 'fluid-slider'
pod 'paper-onboarding'
```

What I am asking is, are there any dangers or potential risks to having this many pods/libraries/sdks that could conflict or cause memory issues?

Comment: Not really. If you app really use all of them, I don't know why you shouldn't use them. Risks? Well, outdated libs, issues on the lib (bug, etc.), conflicts because of dependencies (let's say that CVCalendar depends on ThirdPod on version 2,0, but FireBase depends on ThirdPod on version 4,0, there you'll have issue).

Comment: Okay perfect thanks, thought it was worthwhile asking